# Finding the IP of a router I use

Tags: windows-10, router, home-networking

```
internet connection -> router1 -cable-> router2 -cable-> my desktop
                        |
                        |
                        |-> wifi -> phones
```

The above describes my home network, how do I find out the IP adress of router2? I want to try setting up a second wifi network on it to give wifi coverage to a part of the house that has poor reception, but I can't for the life of me figure out the IP of router2.

A different answer on this site suggested running a tracert, but it points me to router1. Not sure if it is safe to post that output here.

I remember having to change some settings back when I installed this setup to get router2 to correctly pass on router1's signal to my desktop.

I'm using windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

On your desktop, open a command prompt and run the `ipconfig` command.  Look for a line that says "Default Gateway" - this will be your router's IP.  You can access your router most likely by typing in `http://x.x.x.x` in a browser, where x.x.x.x is the router IP.

---

On one of the phones, go through its network settings and check the "Default Gateway".  That will be the IP of router1.

Comment: Which doesn't tell them how to get the address of router 2, which is what they wanted ;)

Comment: Ahh ... that's even simpler.

Comment: Yup. I'll let you do it, save us both saying the same thing ;-)

Comment: `ipconfig` gives me  `192.168.2.254` which, when visited on a webbrowser, brings me to the page of `router1`

Comment: Then router2 is probably a switch and not a router, or only connected to the switch part of a router.  Update your question with the make/model of your devices and where things are plugged in.